# Отформатировать текст регулярным выражением

Tags: php, javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть данные в виде:

```
1.      a   неопределенный артикль
2.      ability способность, возможность
3.      able    знающий, умелый, способный 
4.      about   кругом, повсюду, приблизительно
...
2018.       your    ваш, твой
2019.       yours   ваш, твой
2020.       yourself    себя, себе, сам 
2022.       zero    ноль
```

Нужно убрать всю часть до английского слова/словосочетания, поставить разделитель(в принципе неважно какой) между английским и русским словами/словосочетаниями и после русского слова обрезать до первой встретившейся запятой если есть.

**Пример**:

```
2018.       your    ваш, твой       - было
your|ваш                            - стало
---
1997.       work on продолжать работать  - было
work on|продолжать работать              - стало
```

Нужно регулярное выражения работающее на PHP или JS.

Ссылка на текст: https://pastebin.com/0C3dEWHx

Буду очень благодарен если вместе с регулярным выражение оставите поясняющие комментарии комментарии

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начните, например, с этого:

Регулярка `#(\d+).\s*([a-z]+\s*[a-z]+)\s*([^,\n]+)(?:$|.+)#ium`, строка замены `\1. \2|\3`

Проверим в работе https://regex101.com/r/SUWog4/3

> (\d+)

Выделяем цифры, порядковый номер в первую группу

> ([a-z]+\s*[a-z]+)

Во вторую группу слово латиницей, либо фразу состоящую из двух слов и пробел между ними

> ([^,\n]+)

В третью группу слово на русском, точнее все кроме запятой и переноса строки

> (?:$|.+)

Конец строки или весь остальной остаток строки, в группу не захватываем